# How does face stealing work?

Tags: motherland-fort-salem

In season 2 episode 5 "Brianna's Favorite Pencil" of *Motherland: Fort Salem*, Scylla and Anacostia are planning to steal the face of the local Camarilla chapter leader.

The culmination of this appears to be a destructive collection of said face using similar burning imagery to the concealment spell.

In the final scene of the episode, we see Scylla disguised as Bonnie, who turns out to be alive and well, and presumably unaware her image has been used. The two scenarios don't seem to match up well. Do we know how the face stealing process works?

Comment: I guess, there is stealing face for real and there is pretending to be someone else using an illusion. Probably ASOIAF rules: you can skin somebody's face off and wear it. Or you can use make up, prosthetics and illusion magic to fake it. But I don't have any proof so I'll let someone else reply to this.

Comment: Step 1) Steal face. Step 2) ???. Step 3) Profit!